# Can a single hosts file entry contain multiple domains/sub-domains?

Tags: asp.net, iis, testing, web, hosts

May be this is a weird question, but I am curious to know if single hosts file entry can contain multiple domains on same line?

I know that following is okay for host entry:

```
127.0.0.1 somedomain.com
```

But, I want to know if following would work:

```
127.0.0.1 somedomain.com, alternate-domain.com, subdomain.domain.com
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 somedomain.com, *.domain.com
```

(**Note**: I am doing hosts file entries on windows)

May be this has been asked before, but I googled before writing my question, and I didn't quite find a good answer. Thanks for taking time to read and answering, it will be pretty helpful.

Comment: Yes, but have you tried it? Did something not work?

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work for me on subdomain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hosts file and multiple sub-domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078193/hosts-file-and-multiple-sub-domains)

Comment: That seemed helpful, but I wonder if I am missing something. Because my host file entry is done as the referenced comment says. The subdomain I am trying to visit is on **https**, where as the domain i am moving from is on **http**. May be it was because of something related to SSL?

Comment: I got my answer, see the answer I posted. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

On IIS, I had to add **https** in bindings associating it to use IIS Development Certificate for SSL in my development environment.

Also, in the process I found that both of the following wiil work for me.

```
127.0.0.1 somedomain.com, alternate-domain.com, subdomain.domain.com
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 somedomain.com alternate-domain.com subdomain.domain.com
```

**Spaces** and **commas** both work, and I can add multiple domains, subdomains combinations on same line.

Also, **if you are moving from a non-secure domain to secure domain/subdomain, SSL certificate needs to be setup on web server for it, else it would end up showing an error in the browser.**

Cheers!

Comment: Can you confirm if you are trying it on windows hosts file? Because I tried both and it works for me. Also, please ensure you don't have two host file entries otherwise it had chance of being overridden.

Comment: I tried on Windows Host file. I only have single hosts file.